# Can't create new entry by admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I have model called `Company`. The model pretty simple as you can see. In project I use postgres database.

I have strange problem when try to create new entry by Django admin.

First I add 5 entry in database by sql request from terminal. They have id from 1 to 5. In database client I see them. Now when I try to add new company by admin it raise next error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "company_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(5) already exists.
```

Can someone say how to fix this problem?

**models.py:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

**admin.py:**

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)


admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

Comment: I am not sure but it seems to me that I need to create trigger to insert inside dababase. What do you think about that?

Comment: According to the provided information, `IntegrityError` won't raise.

Comment: delete all entry using django shell and try again...

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset

Comment: @ShihabudheenKM this is not an option for me unfortunately.

Comment: @Selcuk How exactly squashmigrations could help me in this case?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek The link points to `sqlsequencereset`, not `squashmigrations`.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this problem because PostgreSQL uses a sequence to fill the `id` field. Somehow the sequence got out of sync, maybe you assigned an id manually.

You have to reset the sequence used for the primary key in the `Company` model. The [`sqlsequencereset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell) management command will print out the necessary commands.

```
$ python manage.py sqlsequencereset my_app
```

Replace `my_app` with the name of the app that contains the `Company` model. You should be able to pipe its output to the [`dbshell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell) management command.

```
$ python manage.py sqlsequencereset my_app| python manage.py dbshell
```